# Can set up a cron job to copy my server to Amazon S3

Tags: backup, amazon-ec2, replication, amazon-s3

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 install on physical hardware. I will then install [Geonode](http://geonode.org/) on it. The system will be running at a place with variable network capacity.

My colleagues will add data and should not be concerned with the backup issues. The server will mainly be working on a local network, although it will have internet access.

I would like to do a full backup of the server to Amazon S3 at regular intervals. Disk image would be fine.

If possible I would also like the copy to be prepared as an Amazon EC2 image format so that I quickly can run a copy of their system status.

Has anyone done this or something similar before? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Install docker and then install ubuntu inside it(i.e. a container with ubuntu as its base.) and then install Geonode inside it, take backup of docker images as frequently as you want using a cron job. The docker images are of minimal size and are easily portable too.